# Convert list to dictionary but giving the name which is max time repeated in the list

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

Hi I am converting a list to dictionary. The list has names of employees. I want to convert it to dictionary for better performance. But I am getting an error while converting list to dictionary saying key is already added. I need to get the count of names which are more than once by using dictionary. Following is my list

```
List<String> names = new List<String>{
                          "Navin Kabra",
                          "Amit Paranjape",
                          "Navin Kabra",
                          "Amit Paranjape1",
                          "Navin Kotkar",
                          "Gaurav Kotkar"};
```

Here I need to convert the list to dictionary. And using the dictionary i want to find the name which appears max in the list. I tried using linq to convert list to dictionary but error of already key present.

Result of above list will be `Navin Kabra`.
Please advice how I can go about it.

Answer (score 4):

Group by name and count repeated items:

```
var dict = names.GroupBy(o => o).ToDictionary(o => o.Key, o => o.Count());
```

Answer (score 0):

If your only goal is to get the item with the max count, you do not need to create a `Dictionary`. Simply use the following LINQ:

```
var MaxName = names.GroupBy(x => x, y => y.Count()).OrderByDescending(g => g.Count()).Select(g => g.Key).First();
```

Comment: Your group by is wrong. The second parameter would have two arguments to the lambda in order to call Count() on the second argument. Otherwise it's an element selector which would call Count<char>() extension method of the string itself returning its length. I think you just want to do `GroupBy(x=>x).OrderByDescending(...)` otherwise you would need `GroupBy(x=>x, (x, y) => new { Key=x, Count = y.Count()).OrderByDescending(x=> x.Count).First().Key`